# c# guid-field received null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, guid

I have following code:

```
     public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _fileModel = new FileModel { Files = _fileService.GetFilesForArchivation(), IdOfService = default(Guid) };

        return View(_fileModel);
    }
```

and Iv'e implemented two methods also :

```
   public IActionResult Compress()
    {
        //_compressingService.CompressAllFiles();
        _fileModel.IdOfService = _compressResolverService.Start(_serviceProvider);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult CancelCompressing()
    {
        //_compressingService.Stop();
        _compressResolverService.Stop(_fileModel.IdOfService);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

In first method Iv'e added `IdOfService` to FileModel. In second code I am trying to send this field as a parameter. In first method i get normal value of guid but in second method it has default value and i get

> NullReferenceException

Kindly review this issue and give feedback.

Comment: Maybe is my lack of knowledge of MVC, but I wonder what is `_compressResolverService`. Consider editing and adding a [mcve]

Comment: What's actually happening in the `Start` and `Stop` methods?

Comment: It seems that you are relying on member variables in the controller in a unsafe way. You have no guarantee in which order the methods in the controller will be run, and by which users. E.g. both user x and user y may call `Index()` at approximately the same time. Who's `_fileModel` should be stored? User y may overwrite the varialbe `_fileModel` before user x has Called `Compress()` and when user x calls `Compress()` he will act on user y's `_fileModel`. I think you should use `TempData`, `Session`, `Cookie` or return some id to the user to be able to reference the user's instance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from one action to another you are losing your value, you can use

```
TempData["IdOfService"] = _fileModel.IdOfService; 
TempData.Keep();
```

To keep this in "memory".

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking on similar lines. I feel this would resolve his problem.